# Suggest me a better name for an API method

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions, api-design

**Introduction:**

I'm working on an API which provides access to Picasa, Flickr and some other image services.

I have a class WebAlbum (it provides access to nested photos, albums if allowed, and some meta information).

My API allows the user not only to read albums but it also allows them to create new albums. In the general case, in order to create new album, the API user should use a factory method, which creates an album and then call the method `WebGallery#addAlbum (newAlbum)`.

But Flickr doesn't allow creation of empty albums, it requires at least one predefined photo in any new album (to make nice album preview probably). In Flickr terms this first photo is called the `Primary Photo`. So in order to create an album for Flickr, user should use a factory method, then add an image to the new album, and then call `WebGallery#addAlbum (newAlbum)`.

**Problem:**

At the moment WebAlbum class has this method

```
public interface WebAlbum {

   ...

   public boolean requiresPrimaryPhoto ();
}
```

I can't leave this name because PrimaryPhoto is just a Flickr term. I can change it to

```
public interface WebAlbum {

   ...
   //with spaces: requires one added photo to create new album

   public boolean requiresOneAddedPhotoToCreateNewAlbum ();
}
```

Please suggest a shorter name which has the same meaning.

Comment: `requiresOneAddedPhotoToCreateNewAlbum` doesn't sounds good [ even if u add spaces ]

Comment: I wish more people were as concerned as you are about API design

Comment: @RI: I agree. Many APIs (including standard libraries) prefer shorter but ambiguous method names, counting on people to read the documentation. But developers are inherently optimistic - if something looks like it fits the bill, they assume that it does.

Comment: @Rakesh: Research shows that non-novice developers are quite adept at reading CamelCase. I don't think the length is a problem in that sense. My view is that it is better to have one long but unambiguous method name than one which could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`boolean isEmptyAlbumAllowed`

Answer (score 2):

`public boolean needsDefault;`

or, more descriptive

`public boolean needsDefaultImg;`

EDIT
Another question you should ask yourself is if this property even should be exposed.  If you want to make the experience of managing albums consistent on all backends, then maybe your library could provide default images where required.  A logo for your app, maybe.  Users are unlikely to have empty albums for very long anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
public boolean requiresDefaultImage;
```

or

```
public boolean requiresAlbumImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like allowsEmptyAlbum or emptyAlbumPermitted

That being said, adding an extra method means that the user of the class needs to know that this could even be an issue and remember to make the check before adding the album. This could be an issue because most developers "want to get things done fast" and would not know about the differences between services.

Even adding a note in the documentation is not enough because many folks calling "addAlbum" would never read the documentation of the method since it seems straightforward (see my research for details).

Ideally, you would either be able to create different factories for each service (and provide the information there), or, if you have to use a single API, find a way of gracefully failing or maybe adding a placeholder image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it even shorter by removing the redundant Album portion.

```
public boolean canBeEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question:

```
boolean isDefaultPhotoRequired;
```

The longer answer: the default photo requirement isn't shared by all WebAlbums, so it's a perfect candidate for using inheritance.  Move that behavior to a Flickr specific subclass.  You could do something like add the creation of that defaultImage to a Flickr.init().

Answer (score 0):

```
   public boolean requiresInitialPhoto ();

   public boolean doesOnePhotoExist ();

   public boolean needsOnePhoto ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create FlickerWebAlbum and PicasaWebAlbum classes. Each of them will represent behavior specific to each provider.